# What is best and recommended way of using constants in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a Angular 5 application where I want to use

- a. application level constants
- b. Module level constants

I know we can use DI (Injection Token), or Services to use constants, or create a global.ts file with all constants and then access them anywhere.

I wanted to understand what is the best and recommended way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

How i would do it is just create two different namespace 
- ApplicationConstant
- ModuleContants

Then exports the individuals Constant from the namespace eg:

```
export namespace ApplicationConstant {
  export const APP_NAME = 'Todo_list';
}
```

Do not over complicate it, as they are just constant, no need to introduce DI. 
Always try to be independent on the framework unless there is a real need. 
DI is good when you need to mock..etc, but for constant, they are usually just values.

If you use DI (Service), you will have to add it inside the `app-module`..etc then inject that in other places. This is added complexity with no real benefits.

The only benefits I can see if you you use the DI (Service) might be if you want to LazyLoad by modules, however constants are usually really lightweight.

Your `global.ts` is fine, but always encapsulates it in a namespace as my example above, so when you access it, you know where its coming from eg: `ApplicationConstant.APP_NAME`.